# How to dynamically add CSS to a menu on click in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to dynamically add styling to my menu without using 15 different if-else statements. Perhaps a for loop?

`

C#

```
String activepage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

          if (activepage.Contains("Cops"))
            {
                activateCOPS.Attributes.Add("class", "nav-link active");
            }
            else if (activepage.Contains("Opac"))
            {
                activateOPAC.Attributes.Add("class", "nav-link active");
            }
            else if (activepage.Contains("Etp-Tps"))
            {
                activateETP_TPS.Attributes.Add("class", "nav-link active");
            }
            else if (activepage.Contains("Eta"))
            {
                activateETA.Attributes.Add("class", "nav-link active");
            }... etc.
```

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="activateCOPS" class="nav-link" runat="server" href="Cops.aspx">COPS</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="activateOPAC" class="nav-link" runat="server" href="Opac.aspx">OPAC</a>
</li>
```

`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
var themes = new Dictionary<string, Func<string[], bool>
{
     {"Employee", SetEmployeeSiteTheme },
     {"Government", SetGovermentSiteTheme} 
}

 if(themes.ContainsKey("Employee"))
     themes[key].Invoke("Some markup?");
```

Then inside those methods you can find your control, you can modify the markup, you are not generating a thousand if statements and you can expand the functionality later on depending on your needs.

This would be a better structure to control multiple layouts in my mind, this is how I might tackle your problem.  Obviously I did not create a viable solution, I only demonstrated an approach to be a viable solution.

Comment: I was thinking of creating an array of the IDs (Cops, Opac, Etp-Tps, etc.) and looping through each array and setting up an argument against the url if present to add the necessary css styling. What do you think? Is this viable?